# Excel VBA Range 'Delete' method randomly fails

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**

I have a piece of VBA code which deletes multiple rows on a worksheet depending on if the values on each row are TRUE or FALSE in a specific column (a 'control range'). The worksheets as switched as a master loop (above the level of this function) that cycles through multiple sheets and workbooks.

This is used in the Excel 2013 and 2016

Naturally the code searches for matching rows and builds up a range object and only once the loop has ended is that rage deleted.

**Code extract**

I can't send a copy of the actual workbook because it is too large, too complicated and I don't have time to explain how it works - besides it is confidential.

I have listed below an extract of the key code that is failing (with the command that fails in bold).

```
    ' Build up a list of rows which are valid
    For Each rngCurControlCell In rngSheetControlRange.Cells

        If rngCurControlCell.Value = True Then

            If rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngRowsToDelete = rngCurControlCell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set rngRowsToDelete = Union(rngCurControlCell.EntireRow, rngRowsToDelete)
            End If

        End If 'rngCurControlCell.Value = True

    Next rngCurControlCell

    ' Delete the rows
   If Not rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then rngRowsToDelete.Delete
```

**Problem / Issue**

Sometimes this code works and sometimes it does not.

I have put various debugging in the code and can confirm that the code always finds the target rows ('rngRowsToDelete' in the extract above) and **always** builds up the range object correctly.

HOWEVER ... sometimes the delete works and sometimes it does not - even though it it run against the same worksheet. No error is generated.

***Has anyone come across a similar situation / have any thoughts ?***

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes the delete doesn't work - what exactly happens (or doesn't happen)?

Comment: **...and always builds up the range object correctly.** Change the line `If Not rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then rngRowsToDelete.Delete` to `If Not rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then rngRowsToDelete.Delete Else Msgbox "This time no range was found"` Now everytime it doesn't delete anything, do you see the messagebox?

Comment: Yes @SJR ... my constant vicious horizontal reading...

Comment: SJR: I mean that the row does not get deleted. There are no errors generated.

SiddharthRout: this code runs as a silent process (no feedback to user)

This sub that contains this code is being run multiple times in a loop in order to delete rows on multiple different sheets that are marked as TRUE in the specified column of each sheet. As I say the deletion works from some sheets in the some workbooks and not others. If the master process is re-executed against those same 'input' workbooks and sheets you may get different results (i.e. the rows may now be deleted),

Comment: That suggests that `rngRowsToDelete` is Nothing - have you stepped through, or tried Siddharth Rout's suggestion?

Comment: @SJR: As I said in the OP I have already run debugging and can guarantee that the rows are correctly detected and where there are valid rows to be deleted 'rngRowsToDelete is not nothing - hence my confusion. Also the entire row is added to the range of a valid row - not just one cell.

Comment: **1.** Please try what I suggested **2.** Also do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere above in the code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I will have to wait to test until I can arrange testing time with the client who has this issue and the input workbooks. I wanted to collect everyone's thoughts and possible experience with this issue before going back to the client and using testing time. 

I don't use 'on error resume next' as that is bad practice (except for specific circumstances) and certainly would be wrong here. 

The procedure does have a complete error handler (using 'on error goto subErrorHandler') to capture any error and record it but this does not record an error.

Comment: If you try what I suggested and if you do not see a message box and also the row(s) are not deleted then there is a problem and then we will investigate it further. Till then I do not know what else to suggest.

Comment: Also quick check. Do you have `Dim rngRowsToDelete As Range` outside the procedure or inside the procedure? If it is outside the procedure then Add this line `Set rngRowsToDelete = Nothing` right after `If Not rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then rngRowsToDelete.Delete`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well I have previously added debug code and outputted the 'rngRowsToDelete.address' just before the 'deletion line' and the address is correct (i.e. not Nothing) and shows only the entire rows of those rows which are marked as True - so I know that the range is not nothing when it attempts to delete. This is why I have posted because I have uses the same code solution in numerous different projects for about 20 years and this has never failed me - until now.